# Random Variable which takes two distributions with different probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a random variable which is $~N(0,1)$ with probability $0.4$ and $~N(2,1)$ with probability $0.6$. What is the pdf of $X$ ?  Is it gaussian ?

My attempt : Let $f(.)$ represent the pdf of $X$, $f_1(.)$ represent the pdf of $N(0,1)$ and $f_2(.)$ represent the pdf of $N(2,1)$. Then, $ f(x)=0.4 * f_1(x) + 0.6 * f_2(x)$. I don't know if this is correct and also I want to know how to check if $f(.)$ is the pdf of a gaussian.

Thanks.

Comment: You can verify your answer is correct by going through the CDF function: 
$$ Pr[X \leq x]  = Pr[ X \leq x | \mbox{distribution 1}](0.4) + Pr[X \leq x | \mbox{distribution 2}](0.6) $$ Can you finish from there?  Perhaps post your own answer? For intuition on whether it is Gaussian, perhaps you can plot it.

Comment: The derivative of the CDF is $f(x)=\frac{0.4 e^{(-x^2)/2} + 0.6  e^{(-(x-2)^2)/2)}}{\sqrt(2\pi)}$. The image given by MATLAB is attached in my answer. It is not symmetric.

Comment: @Michael Can you please throw some light on the graph of the pdf? Is it gaussian ?

Comment: @AndréNicolas "It is double-humped (bimodal)." No.

Comment: @Did: I will look later to see where I was mistaken, and in the meantime delete the comment.

Answer (score 1):

[image: graph of pdf f(x)]

It is not symmetric. I don't know if we can call this as a gaussian. Is there way to check this without plotting. This question appeared in my exam.

MATLAB Code :

$x=linspace (-10,10,1000000);$

$f=@(x) (0.4 * exp((-x.^2) ./2) + 0.6 * exp((-(x-2).^2)./2))./sqrt(2*pi);$

$plot(x,f(x))$

Comment: Since this seems to obsess you: this PDF is NOT gaussian.

Comment: I was hoping the graph would have two bumps so it would be more obvious it was not Gaussian.  But indeed your observation about asymmetry shows it is not Gaussian.  One way to test this without graphing is to test two points equally spaced to the right and left of hte mean of 1.2:  Does $f(1.2+.8) = f(1.2-.8)$?